# Meaning of "or" in this sentence

Tags: meaning, terminology, logic

In my text book I saw the sentence: *If a request is made to a web service, then the response will be returned within 5 seconds or the service is under DoS attack.*

I cannot understand the usage of or in this sentence. Is it an **exclusive or** meaning that if the response will be returned within 5 seconds then there is no possibility of a DoS attack? Or does it just mean that if no response will be returned in 5 seconds, the service is under DoS attack. I will appreciate any help on understanding this sentence.

Comment: I think it can be inferred from the sentence that  " if the response will not be given within 5 seconds, then you can understand that the service is under Dos attack"

Comment: They should have used 'unless' instead of 'or'.

Comment: I think it should be "otherwise".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's an *exclusive or*, because you can be under attack and still get a response within 5 seconds. I think what you have here is an *inclusive disjunction*, which you can read about [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction).

> ***A*** = The response will be returned within 5 seconds.
>
> ***B*** = The service is under DoS attack.

If ***A*** is false, then ***B*** must be true.
If ***A*** is true, ***B*** can be either true or false.

So if you get a response within 5 seconds, you don't know if the service is under attack or not. Generally speaking, you can assume it's inclusive disjunction unless you're told it's the exclusive-or.